# JavaScript: getting the raw bytes of the page itself

Tags: javascript, http, web, http2, spdy

I'm trying to get the **raw bytes** [1] of a webpage itself as sent by the server.

Is JavaScript even able to do this?

Attempt 1:

```
<!doctype html>
<script>
onload = ()=>{
  console.log(document.body.innerHTML); 
};
</script>
<body> 

pasting raw bytes here, eg:

asdfg <a>  hi  </b> xyz

boundary=gc0p4Jq0M

raw bytes image 1 here

--gc0p4Jq0M

boundary=ggUjM

raw bytes css page 1 here

--ggUjM

boundary=yyJAkM

raw bytes js page 1 here

--yyJAkM

a couple more resources here
```

..doesn't work. [It shows the parsed dom.]

---

1: meaning no or almost no escaping, to keep bandwidth at a minimum.

Comment: Are you sure you need the server response as bytes? Also, do you only want the request body, or all the request headers as well?

Comment: If you query the DOM for content you are always going to get that content as its represented within the DOM which may differ from what the browser downloaded & parsed.  Issuing an Ajax request for the page is one way to get the unparsed content.

Comment: @PeterMader, Back of the body would be all that's needed. I'm trying to use scripting to pull an "image" off the back of the response with as little escaping as possible to keep bandwidth at a minimum. **Raw bytes** is what I'm hoping to achieve.

Comment: @AlexK., Issuing another HTTP would defeat the purpose of the question.

Comment: What is the purpose? What do you need the unparsed HTML code for?

Comment: JavaScript only ever has access to the DOM which, as already noted, is not the same thing as the downloaded source code. Thus I suspect this is impossible without a fresh AJAX call.

Comment: @PeterMader, To compact multiple HTTP requests into 1.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Why do you need to merge HTTP requests? Are `data:` URIs insufficient?

Comment: @zzzzBov, `data` images have base64 overhead.

Comment: @Pacerier how big is this image that the ~33% base64 overhead is larger than the overhead of the script needed to solve the problem? Have you considered looking at an HTTP/2 solution that's more future-friendly?

Comment: @zzzzBov, It's not a single image, but a combination of 10 files of scripts. This is for HTTP 1.1 multiplexing, if HTTP 2 was supported on both the client and server, none of this would be needed.